# Three dot menu for more options in android

Tags: android

I want to show three-dot `Button` in android xml,when clicking on that `Button` it should display  more options. Can any one  help me how to implement the three-dot menu `Button` in android to get the more options.

Comment: The Android ActionBar [automatically overflows](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html) actions that cannot be fit on the display. Where are you stuck, what have you tried already? It seems like what you're asking for is the default behavior.

Comment: create a menu, if the device does not have a menu hard-button, the 3 dots will appear on the screen, otherwise, the menu hard-button will be used

Answer (score 2):

Just create an XML file inside `res/menu` and inflate it this way

```
// inside activity
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.game_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

And the XML should be something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/new_game"
          android:title="@string/new_game"
          android:showAsAction="never"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/help"
          android:title="@string/help"
          android:showAsAction="never"/>
</menu>
```

Read this for more information: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html

Comment: This is not solution iam looking for.U can find the same scenario in camera apps in kitkat version.thats what i exactly need

Comment: What about you post some more of what you need, an image or something, we are not going to know unless you tell us

Comment: In the kitkat version there is a one camera apps in which we can see one black rounded button with three dots inside in it.when we press that button it will show more options.i am looking for how to do it exactly like that.

Comment: That's just a `Button` with a 3 dot image as a background. To do that just create the whole menu and set its visibility to View.INVISIBLE, and finally chage it to View.VISIBLE on button's click